# PHP regex string to format chatting dialog with error preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex

I'm formating for a chatting dialog bellow:

- Dalvik: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
- Jenni:  Suspendisse facilisis pretium ante,
- Dalvik: Vivamus feugiat dui ut libero rhoncus nec porttitor velit posuere.
- Jenni: Aenean porttitor ipsum eu metus adipiscing
- Dalvik: **(Sed vehicula:** magna vitae nulla
- Jenni: sed dui quam, vitae consectetur dui.
- Jenni: Curabitur vulputate ante :)

The bold text above ; it make error in my replace statment:

```
$name = self::getNameFromMessage($textFormat);
$color = self::getNewTextColor();
$replacement = "<br/><font color='$color'>$name</font>:";
$textFormat = preg_replace(
           $pattern = "/$name :\s/i", //find $name in $textFormat and set text color
           $replacement, 
           $subject = $textFormat
);
```

**Error**: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 15

Can you suggest me a better regex string?

Comment: Not really sure if you want to highlight the user name or the comment itself, you could try something like this for the username: http://regexr.com?30v1u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error was caused by not quoting your regex, in your example, the regex finds a `(`, then it expects to find a closing `)`. If you want to match a literal `()` or other regex meta-characters, you need to quote your regex:

```
$pattern = preg_quote("/$name :\s/i");
```